Is it possible to limit git fetch -f --tags to only the tags matching the given pattern and in the given time window (e.g. since past 24 hours)?
When I run git fetch -f --tags it fetches gazillion tags and takes quite some time to run. In reality I just need tags matching a certain name pattern that were created since the last time I ran the command. But I will be satisfied being able to provide one of these conditions, if both are not possible.
Is there a way to do it?

Replace abc123 with the tag name you want to fetch.
git fetch origin 'refs/tags/abc123*:refs/tags/abc123*'
You can list the tags like this;
git tag -l 'abc123*'

So this fetches only the tags themselves, right? If I want to have the same effect as git fetch -f --tags I should invoke git fetch first, correct? Also what about the -f flag?

git fetch origin 'refs/tags/abc123*:refs/tags/abc123*'``` will have the same effect as  the same effect as ```git fetch -f --tags```. The first command, git fetch, fetches the latest changes from the remote repository, including branches and commits, but does not update the local tags. -f is force. It will force overwrite any local references that may conflict with the remote references being fetched.

I guess there is no way to also limit temporally?

@mark: no, there is no way to send that kind of filter to the server. Note that you can also use git ls-remote to list references without fetching them, and filter from that.

also: if the remote is hosted on a known service (GitHub, gitlab, ...) you may use the API to get information such as dates

Tags matching a pattern and pointing into the fetched history is far enough off the beaten path that you'll have to build it yourself.
It's not all that hard, Git provides all the data you'll need to do it. I can think of two ways offhand: fetch with all the tags and then delete any new ones that don't match the pattern, and fetch none of the tags initially then go back and fetch any tags matching that pattern that do point into that history.
My first attempt would be the first method, full fetch followed by deleting the unwanted tag refs,
git fetch -f &&
awk '   $3~/^tag/ { 
        split($3,memo,"'\''")
        if (memo[2]!~/^abc.*/)
                print "delete",memo[2]
        }
' FS=$'\t' .git/FETCH_HEAD \
| git update-ref --stdin


the other way would be to git verify-pack -v the pack that results from git fetch -nfk, git ls-remote for all remote tags matching your pattern, and explicitly fetch any that point to a commit you found in that pack.
For the alternate way, commits in the most recent pack:
git verify-pack -v $(find .git/objects/pack -type f -exec ls -t {} + | sed q) \
| awk '$2=="commit" { print $1 }'

origin tags matching a pattern:
git ls-remote origin refs/tags/abc123\*

and the rest of the reformatting and selection for this method I'll leave as an exercise 'cause I'm like that.

It will take me time to grok your response. +1 for all the information. Thank you very much.
